# Flutter Facebook App Events gives the error: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appEventsLogger has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am using the latest version of [FaceBook App Events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) plugin in Flutter with the latest version of Flutter as well. On click event, I am calling the logEvent method like this:

```
facebookAppEvents.logEvent(
    name: 'Link Clicked',
    parameters: {'url': request.url},
);
```

where the facebookAppEvents defined and initialized in the class itself:

```
static final facebookAppEvents = FacebookAppEvents();
```

Advertiser tracking is working with no problem using the following statement:

```
facebookAppEvents.setAdvertiserTracking(enabled: true);
```

However, I am getting an exception when calling the logEvent method. The exception is:

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(26467): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(26467): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appEventsLogger has not been initialized
```

Flutter doctor has no problem nor warning. I tried to clean and rebuild the project but still getting the same exception. All the tests I did are on Android only.
Any way to fix this?

Comment: I updated flutter to the latest version and all the packages as well and used the latest Java and Gradle and it worked. However, did not know the exact reason of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue after many tries and the problem was that I defined the ApplicationId and ClientToken in the wrong position inside AndroidManifest.xml
so make sure to define the string resource reference to your main AndroidManifest.xml file, directly under the  tag, also do not forget to use a real mobile with a Facebook account.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
...
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This library has a bug in it's source code.
If you paste the exact stack trace I might be able to pin point the bug and maybe send a patch to the library owner for review.

Their code (where "appEventsLogger" is defined):
https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/blob/develop/android/src/main/kotlin/id/oddbit/flutter/facebook_app_events/FacebookAppEventsPlugin.kt

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
I updated flutter to the latest version and all the packages as well and used the latest Java and Gradle and it worked. However, did not know the exact reason of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I added ApplicationId meta data only because the flutter plugin documentation [said so](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) and got the error. But then solved it by adding ClientToken to AndroidManifest.xml ( you should add facebook_client_token as a string resource as well )

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

</application>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">123123</string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token">456456</string>
</resources>
```

More Info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android